# Jitpack repository retrieved wrong version of dependency

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, jitpack

I tried to use JitPack to add a forked library to my Android project.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'}
    }
}
```

After sync, my library was added correctly, but the problem is, the newest version of dependencies like `Picasso` and `okio` was retrieved, other than the version specified in gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Also tried to use `includeGroup` to only retrieve my own library via JitPack, but it still get the newest packages somehow.

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex "com\\.github\\.myusername.*"
            }}
```

I assume it's a maven repository problem but don't really understand what's going on. Any suggestion is welcomed!

Comment: Do you have other dependencies in your build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes, a bunch of androidx packages, firebase, and others. But they are fine since they are using newest version anyway.

Comment: Run the `app:dependencies` or  `app:dependencyInsight`. Some of other dependencies can have a transitive dependency on the newest version. Gradle in this case downloads only the newest versions and not the version specified in build.gradle

Comment: Good idea, I'll give it a try.

Comment: You are right. The library I forked use `picasso` and `okio` as dependencies. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Maven dependencies are specified as

```
groupid:artifact:version
```

On most Maven repositories, they are taken from the `pom.xml` of the library.

JitPack works differently here:

- the `groupid` identifies the git hosting service and user, e.g. `com.gitlab.johndoe`
- `artifact` is the project name on that git hosting service, as found in the URL
- `version` is a git ref, i.e. a tag or branch name, or a commit hash

There are ways to keep these in sync:

- for the domain that corresponds to your `groupid`, configure a TXT record with a URL which points to the corresponding user or organization at the git hoster
- choose the artifact name and project name to be the same
- tag each release in git with the version number it has in `pom.xml`.

Otherwise, you will have to modify your dependencies so JitPack will find them.